# Entire function and injectivity

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, laurent-series, entire-functions

So if $f(z)=az+b$, is an entire injective map from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$, for both a and b are complex numbers and a is not equal to 0.

I've proved that if f is an injective entire function, it cannot have an essential singularity at infinity, but then how to show that $f(z)$ has to be a polynomial? And why $f(z)$ has to satisfy that $f(z)=az+b$?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307185

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First since $f$ is an injective entire function, $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} f(z) = \infty$. (This is because if $f$ is bounded entire, then $f$ would be constant.)

Next suppose $f$ has Taylor series
$$
f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n \quad\text{and }\quad g(z) =f(1/z) =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{z^n}
$$
If $f$ is not polynomial, then $0$ is an essential singularity of $g$ ($\infty$ is an essential singularity of $f$). By Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, for any $A\in \Bbb{C}$, there is a sequence $z_n\to0$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(z_n)=A$, i.e. there is $z_n'=1/z_n\to\infty$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(z_n')=A$, contradicting $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$.

Finally any polynomial with degree more than one has more than one root and thus can't be injective.

Comment: It may be possible that polynomial have same root with  multiplicity.

Comment: How to remove that

Comment: Polynomial have same root with multiplicity can not be injective .

Comment: Thanks Sir I just got that proof

Comment: @hermes: Why $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$? $f$ might just diverge without tending to any number or $\infty$.