# How to show that any biholomorphism between $\mathbb C$ and itself is linear?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

In complex analysis textbooks $\mathrm{Aut}\,(\mathbb C)$  frequently serves as an example of conformal automorphism groups, which is said to consist of all linear functions $az+b$ with $a\neq0$. Equivalently it means that any biholomorphism $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is of the form $az+b$ where $a\neq0$.

However, all textbooks that I have say this fact is obvious but I cannot see it, so I want to ask how to prove it?

Comment: I would be very surprised if an introductory complex analysis textbook actually claimed this was obvious, without providing more context (e.g., a result that it is a corollary of).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307185/automorphisms-of-the-complex-plane

Comment: I wouldn't say it's obvious.  Usually you look at the nature of the singularity at $\infty$; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307185/automorphisms-of-the-complex-plane.  The easiest proof is big Picard, which tells you about the behavior of the function at $\infty$