# Prove that for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$ it is true that $z + \sin z = w$ has exactly one root $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Prove that for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$ it is true that $z + \sin z = w$ has exactly one root $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

The idea I have is to use Rouche's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. It says that the function $f(z)=z+\sin(z)$ is a bijection from $\mathbb C$ to itself; in fact it's fairly well known and not hard to prove that the only holomorphic bijections of the plane are of the form $az+b$.

(Say $g\in H(\mathbb C)$. If $g$ is not a polynomial then it has an essential singularity at $\infty$, so Weierstrass tells us it cannot be injective, since the image of every neighborhood of $\infty$ is open and dense. Otoh if $g$ is a polynomial it cannot be injective if the degree is greater than $1$. So in fact the only *injective* entire functions are of the form $az+b$.)

**Or in yet more detail:** Say $g$ has an essential singularity, say at $0$. Say $0<r<|p|$, and let $V=g(D(p,r))$. Then $V$ is a nonempty open set. Let $W=g(\{z:0<|z|<|p|-r\})$. Then Weierstrass says $W$ is dense. Hence $W\cap V\ne\emptyset$, so $g$ is not injective.

Comment: Why dont you show us the prove since it is not hard and fairly easy?

Comment: I just did.....

Comment: You think Picards theorem is a random theorem? that is highly difficult if not the most difficult theorem I have ever met

Comment: I cited Picard because it's well known.

Comment: By the way your answer seems correct I did not down vote you

Comment: Fine. I just gave a more elementary sliighly longer argument.

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: @GuyFsone Yes, the result of $W$ that I cite _is_  elementary. Say $g$ has an isolated singularity at $p$. If  the image of some deleted neighborhood of $p$ iis not dense then there exists $\alpha$ such that $1/(g-\alpha)$ is bounded near $p$. So $1/(g-\alpha)$ has a removable singularity, hence $g$ has a removable singularity or a pole.

Comment: There is a [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307185/automorphisms-of-the-complex-plane) of automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ on this site.

Comment: People who downvote should comment explaining what the problem is